# identify surface mount component: SOT223 marked IY20903 newline 112115

Tags: identification, surface-mount

This component is likely some sort of power transistor, but the markings a very small and hard to read because of the reflection from the conformal coating.

```
package: SOT223 (black 3-pin SMT package with cooling flange)
markings: IY20903 (very uncertain about this, very hard to read) newline 112115
pcb-id: LIC110 (visible in photo below pin1 of component)
```

Please have a look and see if you can identify it. I had no luck with many online searches. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The image is too dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a [Analog Devices LT1121IST-5](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Analog-Devices-LT1121IST-5-PBF_C661289.pdf) LDO and the actual marking is

```
LT209e3
1121I5
```

(the 'e3' is not always rotated like in the image, see for example [LT1117IST](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Linear-Voltage-Regulators-LDO_Analog-Devices-LT1117IST-5-PBF_C117071.html))
[image]

(Source: [alibaba.com](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/-electronic-components-1121I5-LT1121IST-5_1600479401897.html))

Here is my reasoning:

- The pinout is reasonable
- The designator L**IC**xxx makes more sense for a LDO regulator than a transistor
- The Linear Technology 'LT' logo could be interpreted as 'IY' under conformal coating (especially with the old marking style, see last picture)
- If 'e3' is not roated, the top line would read LT + 5 characters like described
- The bottom line '1121I5' is very close to what is described
- The last '1' in your picture looks more like an 'I' to me

---

A picture of the LT1117IST as reference, I think your part uses this older marking style:

[image]

(Source: lcsc.com)

Comment: Great detective work. Your analysis looks very promising. I'll do some measurements tomorrow and see if that might confirm the identity.

Comment: I think answer is correct, thanks much.